# Shopify webhook verification in parse

Tags: parse-platform, shopify

I am trying to get a shopify webhook to fill my customer class in parse.com, however something must go wrong. I don't know how to verify the parse response since Shopify sends this webhook out from it's ruby backend. I used requestbin to catch the webhook and I replicated a post request using postman to my parse url and everything works fine. Does anyone know how to debug requests like these? Is there a console in Parse where I can see all the incoming requests and the responses Parse.com sent back?

Comment: i am embedding my authentication headers in my url like so: https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm

Comment: Why don't you get your customer data using Shopify API instead of webhooks? It's really strange that requestbin successfully gets your data from Shopify but when sending that to parse fails. Did you deeply check the postman side? Did you try with Shopify orders or products?

Comment: The purpose is a private app that tags the customers according to their orders. I could run a cron job of some sort, but it would be nice to catch the webhook and store them one by one. I am currently doing this in my laravel API. I just think Parse.com would be so much easier. I ran the requests through runscope as suggested below and I discovered I am getting an unauthorized error. I'm gonna do some research in that direction. I managed to catch the webhook using a parse.com function, but want to try catching it using the REST API. Gonna do some more investigating...

Comment: would you mind sharing your experience with parse-shopify-webhooks? I find parse very interesting but don't know where to start with

Comment: :) yes for sure, as soon as i find out how I can make it work. I will post back

Comment: i posted on the parse dev forum ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/shopify/parse-developers/racZCLky1Uw/WxBFErHUZI0J )and asked in the ask parse anything series: http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/ask-parse-anything/620232. Still haven't had a response yet, maybe I'll just set up a generic proxy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Runscope for debugging webhooks. Full guide here: https://www.runscope.com/provider-guide/troubleshooting-webhooks - this is more than just a request bin. It's a full transparent proxy that will, like a bin, record the webhook notification, but will also pass it along to the intended destination (your webhook receiver) and record that response as well.